# get data from an array in php through looping

Tags: php

i am new to php and i have array like

```
Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [sub_cat_id] => 4
        [sub_cat_name] => Classics
        [cat_id] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [sub_cat_id] => 6
        [sub_cat_name] => New releases
        [cat_id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [sub_cat_id] => 7
        [sub_cat_name] => Bollywood
        [cat_id] => 2
    )

)
```

i want to loop through this array to get indices and values so that i could use it in

```
<option value="<?php echo $res[index][value];?>"><?php echo $res$res[index][value];?></option>
```

i know its possible through foreach loop but dont know the correct way.

Comment: Foreach is the correct way..:)

Comment: http://php.net/foreach - what you name *Index* in your question in PHP is often called *Key*. But is correct, just saying if you're looking for resources. See as well http://php.net/array . Also you can improve your question by showing the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `foreach` like

```
<?php 
    foreach($my_arr as $res) { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $res['sub_cat_id'];?>">
           <?php echo $res['sub_cat_name'];?>
       </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Consider that `$my_arr` is your array.

Comment: if you want both key & value, just use `foreach($my_arr as $index => $value)` so that you'll get index as $index and value as $value

Comment: You can do in that way also but then may you need to check for the sub_cat_id and sub_cat_name..I thnk

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following may work for you:

```
<?php
foreach ($bigArray as $index => $smallArray)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$smallArray['sub_cat_id'].'">'.$smallArray['sub_cat_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a=array(array('sub_cat_id' => 4,
   'sub_cat_name' => 'Classics',
   'cat_id' => 2),
   array('sub_cat_id' => 6,
   'sub_cat_name' => 'New releases',
   'cat_id' => 2),
   array('sub_cat_id' => 7,
   'sub_cat_name' => 'Bollywood',
   'cat_id' => 2)
  );

  $option='';
  foreach($a as $key=>$value)
  {

    $option.='<option value="'.$value['sub_cat_id'].'">'.$value['sub_cat_name'].'</option>';

  }
```